# Remove SharePoint Group from Folder (not from List)

Tags: powershell, permissions, folder

I need to develop a PowerShell script to remove a group from a folder. Here's an example to illustrate my question. I have a document library named HR. In that document library, I have a folder (with unique permissions) named Benefits. A group named currEmployees has read access to the folder named Benefits. How would I remove currEmployees' access to Benefits?

I am asking how to remove a SharePoint group from a SharePoint folder. I have found examples that explain how to remove a group from a list -- but I need to remove a group from a folder within a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$sitecol = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webURL)
$web = $sitecol.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists["HR"]
$foldername="Benefits"
$folder = $list.ParentWeb.GetFolder($web.Url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url + "/" + $foldername)
$group = $foler.Item.RoleAssignments.Groups["currEmployees"];
$folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove($group)
$folder.Item.Update()
```